# Adding Spring Applicationcontext to a Class (in my case: Hadoop Mapper Class)

Tags: spring, hadoop, spring-data

I'm writing an application/test with spring-batch, containing hadoop mapreduce jobs.

For the spring-batch container everything is fine: I'm loading the Applicationcontext specific configurations before executing the Unittests.

(Code from the spring-data hadoop examples) http://static.springsource.org/spring-hadoop/docs/current/reference/html/batch-wordcount.html

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("/launch-context.xml")
public class WordCountWorkflowTest {

      @Autowired
      private ApplicationContext ctx;
```

When I need to load a Applicationcontext from a main method i found a suggestion to do it the following way:

```java
public class Main {
      public static void main(String[] arguments) {
          ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
      }
}
```

Now I'm searching for a method to kickstart the Applicationcontext from inside the Hadoop Mapper class. My problem: the class itself will get the beans injected. I think usually you have another class or object starting the Applicationcontext for you.

The following method seems to work for me (But I don’t know if there are some pitfalls or nicer methods eg. with annotations):

```java
public class ToHBaseMapper extends
        Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

    private static final String[] CONFIGS = new String[] { "/mapReduce-context.xml" };

    private static AbstractApplicationContext ctx;

    // Executed when class is loaded
    static {
        ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(CONFIGS);
        ctx.registerShutdownHook();
    }
    ...
```

TIA, R